# How to remove this shower drain grate (or otherwise remove mold from the pipe underneath)?

Tags: drain, mold

[image: shower drain with screws removed]

As you can see, there is black mold growing inside the white pipe under this shower drain cover.

I've removed the 2 screws. The silver metal circular grate still feels stuck.

If I try to pry it out with a screwdriver, it feels like I'm going to bend and maybe destroy it.

Are these threaded and screwed-in somehow?

How can I remove it?

Alternatively, how could I do a thorough cleaning of the pipe without removing it? (I've already tried vinegar and baking soda, which had no effect.)

P.S. It says UPC® on one side, Made in USA, and SC (where the S and C are on either side of an dual-triangle hourglass shape).

Comment: I wonder if SC  = Sioux Chief. I found https://www.siouxchief.com/products/drainage/residential/shower-drains. I will email their support.

Comment: That type of drain cover is usually held in place with only the two screws. You can try turning it but screw-on covers generally don't have screws. Probably has some soap scum and calcification holding it. Gently pry it up and you can scrub the inside of the drain with a cleaner of your choice. A bleach solution is very effective against mold.

Comment: The cover may have been embedded in silicone before being screwed down (severe overkill and a pain for future maintainers, as you've found - no other benefit). Or, it might have been mortared in place by the grout job. In either case, destruction _could_ be the only option, but it's certainly _not_ the first option.

Comment: bleach spray should knock that mold down, likely even w/o removal of the grate.

Comment: Yeah - looking again, that may be silicone caulk around the edge. Run a blade around it and it should pry up.

Comment: You all have been so helpful. Thanks for the blade suggestion, @gnicko! I'd accept your answer if you submit. What I did was run a razor around the perimeter, and I thought it was useless because it didn't *seem* to be getting in between the grate and the surrounding, and I don't think there was any silicone or anything there, but I noticed plastic or something accruing on the razor, so it was doing *something*. Then I used 1 screwdriver to pry from one of the square openings, and ...

Comment: ... then I used a 2nd slim screwdriver to catch and pry as soon as I was able to get the grate the tiniest bit lifted (and then pry more using that 2nd one). Thanks!

Comment: Even if it wasn't caulked you have to bonk it with the back end of a screwdriver a few times. Either way, don't worry; readily available at the store as a replacement cover or the whole fitting that comes with one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try running a very sharp knife or razor blade around the edge of the cover plate to help break the seal of what might be holding it. It looks like there's caulk or grout in there. I'm not sure you'll notice much of a change, but it could help get a hold under the edge and aid you in gently prying it up.

Answer (score 0):

What I did was run a razor around the perimeter, and I thought it was useless because it didn't seem to be getting in between the grate and the surrounding, and I don't think there was any silicone or anything there, but I noticed plastic or something accruing on the razor, so it was doing something.

Then I used 1 screwdriver to pry from one of the square openings, and then I used a 2nd slim screwdriver to catch and pry as soon as I was able to get the grate the tiniest bit lifted (and then pry more using that 2nd one). Thanks!